# react-native-maps - polygon onPress event

Tags: react-native, maps, polygon

I'm using react-native-maps and I'm rendering Polygons on my map that I want to be pressable.

My problem is that AFAIK react-native-maps Polygon doesn't have an onPress event.

I also thought about wrapping each Polygon with a Touchable component, but then my problem is that (again, AFAIK...), overlays in react-native-maps have to be direct children of the MapView component or else they won't render...

Any way to get this working?

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I got this answer from https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/488.

The idea is to add an `onPress` event to the `MapView` component like so:

```
<MapView onPress={ this.mapPressed }>
```

Then, using [geojson-js-utils](https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils) you can do (double array is on purpose, that's the way the function works):

```
import { pointInPolygon } from 'geojson-utils';

mapPressed(event) {
 const pointCoords = [event.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude,
                     event.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude];

 const polygonCoords = [ [lngA, latA], [lngB, latB] ... etc... ];

 const  inPolygon = pointInPolygon(
   { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': pointCoords },
   { 'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [plotCoords] }
 );

 if (inPolygon) {
  // do something 
 }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Now there is an onPress event on the Polygon.

Reference: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polygon.md

```
<Polygon
    coordinates={this.props.coordinates}
    strokeColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
    strokeWidth={3}
    tappable={true}
    onPress={() => this.onPress('foo')}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this today and my workaround for now is to place a separate `MapView.Marker` component on the same coordinates, which does have an `onPress` prop assigned.

You'll have to make an effort to have it match the polygon or some other similar behaviour.

I'll follow this question for better solutions anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Doesn't using a marker fore the user to touch the exact coordinate of the marker?

Comment: Well, yes, but I used a custom marker to which I specified a reasonable size so the user touches, and doesn't really render anything visually.

Comment: Marked your answer as correct for now as.... it works :-) 
Do you have any good way of setting the marker size according to the polygon size, or did you give it a static size?

Comment: Yeah, it's more of an ugly workaround. And no, I ended up setting a static size since in my case it wasn't that important that the whole polygon is touchable. In fact, I used an image that needed to go there.

But you may be able to at least, approximate the layout of the polygon with that other marker. 

Good luck with that!

Comment: Posted a better answer I found